# Is there an archive/database of ISS telemetry over time?

Tags: iss, telemetry

I'm trying to find a database of the ISS's telemetry (specifically, its pitch and yaw) over time. All I've found so far is live streaming, like http://www.telemetry.space/, which gives the realtime values. Specifically, I am just looking for the pitch and roll.

Answer (score 5):

**Within the NASA firewall:** yes, there is a service available to bring up recorded telemetry.  I've not used it personally, but I know it's available.

**Publicly:**  The only archives I know of are where people personally recorded data from the ISS Live LightStreamer service, which is what all the various websites (telemetry.space included) use to stream their data.  One coworker of mine has approximately two months' worth of recorded data.  I'll ask him next time I see him if he would be amenable to sharing it in some form.

Edit to Update: ISS Live is functional again!  You can view all the available public telemetry [here](https://iss-mimic.github.io/Mimic/)

Comment: Good (and sad) to know, Tristan. I'm looking for the telemetry for very specific dates and times in 2015 and 2016, so I guess I'll try contacting the good folks at NASA...